# Access to Bind Parameters in MyBatis Interceptor

Tags: mybatis

How do I read the bind parameters inside a MyBatis Interceptor? I'm trying to extract those information so I can write them to a log table.

The guide (http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html) didn't mention how to get them, and the JavaDoc (http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/es/apidocs/org/apache/ibatis/mapping/BoundSql.html) does not have a single line of comment. I saw an example on SO about constructing a new BoundSql but that isn't what I needed.

I tried to test what contents are stored in BoundSql.getParameterMappings() and BoundSql.getParameterObject(), but it seems to be pretty complex. There's JavaType and JdbcType, and if there's only one parameter the ParameterObject isn't a Map object.

What is the proper way to get the bind parameters from BoundSql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through MyBatis source code (where comment is an endangered species), I found out how MyBatis processes the bind parameters. However, that requires access to the JDBC Statement object, which is simply not available inside an Interceptor.

Then I did some testing and settled on this:

1. If there is only a single parameter, BindSql.getParameterObject() will give you the parameter itself. By using BindSql.getParameterMappings() and ParameterMapping.getJavaType() I can tell which Java class the parameter is.
2. If there are more than one parameter, BindSql.getParameterObject() will return an instance of org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.ParamMap, which extends HashMap, or it will be an instance of the DTO you used. Using .getProperty() from ParameterMapping as key or as getter name, you can process the bind parameters one by one.

If anyone has a better way to do this, I'm all ears.